# I want to put these two functions in one function

Tags: javascript, html, function

These two statements are identical, I want to make one statement that is equivalent to them.

In other words I want to make a shortcut of these codes as one function.

```
  function chose1() {          
       if (document.getElementById("Button1").click = true) {
           if (document.getElementById('Button1').value == "") {
               document.getElementById('Button1').value += nextTurn;
               document.getElementById('Button1').style.fontSize = "30px";
               document.getElementById('Button1').style.color = 'Blue';
               if (document.getElementById('Button1').value == "O") {
                   document.getElementById('Button1').style.color = 'Red'
               }
                   changeTurn();
           } 
       } 

       }
       function chose2() {
           if (document.getElementById("Button2").click = true) {
               if (document.getElementById('Button2').value == "") {
                   document.getElementById('Button2').value += nextTurn;
                   document.getElementById('Button2').style.fontSize = "30px";
                   document.getElementById('Button2').style.color = 'Blue';
                   if (document.getElementById('Button2').value == "O") {
                       document.getElementById('Button2').style.color = 'Red'
                   }
                   changeTurn();
               } 
           } 

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function chose(id) { 
       var btn = document.getElementById(id)
       if (btn.click = true) {
           if (btn.value == "") {
               btn.value += nextTurn;
               btn.style.fontSize = "30px";
               btn.style.color = 'Blue';
               if (btn.value == "O") {
                   btn.style.color = 'Red'
               }
               changeTurn();
           } 
       } 

chose("Button1");
chose("Button2");
```

This is the solution , not only for joinig two functions into two but look at how many times in one function you are accessing the dom element like `document.getElementById()` , its leads to performance degrade.
Store the reference in a variable and reuse it. like

```
var btn = document.getElementById(id)
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

```
function chose( id ) { }
```

Then you use `id` instead of "Button1" or "Button2" ; have you searched before asking ?...

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Refactoring`. This world have many good books about it.

You can do:

```
function chose(button) {       
  clickedButton = document.getElementById(button);

       if (clickedButton.click = true) {
           if (clickedButton.value == "") {
               clickedButton.value += nextTurn;
               clickedButton.style.fontSize = "30px";
               clickedButton.style.color = 'Blue';
               if (clickedButton.value == "O") {
                   clickedButton.style.color = 'Red'
               }
                   changeTurn();
           } 
       } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor into a single method that accepts what is variable (the button id). And i suggestion i give to you, which will give you a better
organization and performance is to assign a variable with the result of the: document.getElementById(button_id), instead of on each line making this evaluation you
can put on a variable.

```
function _buttonChoser(button_id) {
  var button_element = document.getElementById(button_id);
   if (button_element.click = true) {
       if (button_element.value == "") {
           button_element.value += nextTurn;
           button_element.style.fontSize = "30px";
           button_element.style.color = 'Blue';
           if (button_element.value == "O") {
               button_element.style.color = 'Red'
           }
           changeTurn();
       } 
   }
};

function chose1() {          
  _buttonChoser('Button1')
};
function chose2() {
  _buttonChoser('Button2')
};
```